# C programming: Sorting Structures with two parameters

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct, qsort

I'm Now trying to sort the Last names and Company names. The user has to enter either a last name or company name (only one). this is my code right now:

```
struct store {
unsigned long phone_num;
char *first_name;
char *last_name;
char *company_name;
char *email;
};
typedef struct store store;


void findContact(FILE *fp, long fileEnd)
{
/*variables*/
char fName [100];
char lName [100];
char cName [100];
char email [100];

int i, length;
int count = 1;
int size = sizeof(long);
int usize = sizeof(unsigned long);

unsigned long phone;

long nextPosition = 0;
long fNamePosition = 0;
long lNamePosition = 0;
long cNamePosition = 0;
long emailPosition = 0;

store *list;
list = malloc(sizeof(store));

/*Search for Contact position in file*/
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); /*Seeks to beginning of file*/
do {
    i = count - 1;

    fread(&phone, usize, 1, fp); /*reads phonenumber of contact*/
    fread(&fNamePosition, size , 1, fp);
    fread(&lNamePosition, size, 1, fp);
    fread(&cNamePosition, size, 1, fp);
    fread(&emailPosition, size, 1, fp);
    fread(&nextPosition, size, 1, fp);

    if(fNamePosition != 0) {

        fseek(fp,fNamePosition,SEEK_SET);
        if(lNamePosition == 0) {
          length = cNamePosition - fNamePosition;
        } else {
          length = lNamePosition - fNamePosition;
        }
        fread(fName,sizeof(char),length,fp);
    } else {
        strcpy(fName," ");
    }

    if(lNamePosition != 0) {
        fseek(fp,lNamePosition,SEEK_SET);
        if (cNamePosition == 0) {
          length = emailPosition - lNamePosition;
        } else {
          length = cNamePosition - lNamePosition;
        }
        fread(lName,sizeof(char), length,fp);
    } else {
        strcpy(lName," ");
    }

    if(cNamePosition != 0) {
        fseek(fp,cNamePosition,SEEK_SET);
        length = emailPosition-cNamePosition;
        fread(cName,sizeof(char), length,fp);
    } else {
        strcpy(cName," ");
    }

    fseek(fp,emailPosition,SEEK_SET);
    length = nextPosition - emailPosition;
    fread(email,sizeof(char),length,fp);

    list = realloc(list, count * sizeof(store));

    list[i].phone_num = phone;
    list[i].first_name = (char *) malloc(strlen(fName) + 1);
    strcpy(list[i].first_name, fName);
    list[i].last_name = (char *) malloc(strlen(lName) + 1);
    strcpy(list[i].last_name, lName);
    list[i].company_name = (char *) malloc(strlen(cName) + 1);
    strcpy(list[i].company_name, cName);
    list[i].email = (char *) malloc(strlen(email) + 1);
    strcpy(list[i].email, email);

    count++;

} while (ftell(fp) != fileEnd);

count--;

qsort(list, count, sizeof(store), compareStore);

/*Prints output*/
for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
    printf("First Name: %s\n", list[i].first_name);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n", list[i].last_name);
    printf("Company Name: %s\n", list[i].company_name);
    printf("Phone Number (enter only numbers): %ld\n", list[i].phone_num);
    printf("Email: %s\n", list[i].email);

    free(list[i].first_name);
    free(list[i].last_name);
    free(list[i].company_name);
    free(list[i].email);
}

free(list);
return;
}


int compareStore (const void*a, const void *b)
{
    const store *aa = a;
    const store *bb = b;

    return (strcmp(bb->last_name, aa->last_name));
}
```

This is my output as of now. It should consider both last name and company name as the same parameters and then sort them:

```
First Name: Andre
Last Name: D'Souza
Company Name:
Phone Number (enter only numbers): 6474000964
Email: adsouz03@mail.com
First Name:
Last Name:
Company Name: University of Guelph
Phone Number (enter only numbers): 5192137299
Email: uog@mail.com
First Name: Raf
Last Name:
Company Name: Raffy Taffy
Phone Number (enter only numbers): 1234567
Email: raf@mail.com
```

Comment: You may significantly benefit from looking at [**qsort won't sort dynamically allocated array of structs**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163754/qsort-wont-sort-dynamically-allocated-array-of-structs)

Answer (score 2):

Your compare function looks wrong. You are passed pointers to two records a and b. These are pointers to your store struct, but you are casting them as store** for some reason, then trying to dereference this as a store*. This has the effect of using the data as pointers, which will certainly cause a segmentation fault.

I suggest:

```
int compareStore (const void*a, const void *b)
{
    const store *aa = a;
    const store *bb = b;

    return (strcmp(aa->last_name, bb->last_name)); 
}
```

Note that `strcmp` returns exactly the kind of int that `qsort` is expecting. Just return `qsort` the value returned by `strcmp`.

To generalize `compareStore` to check either Last name or Company name, assume that one of these contains a string, and the other is either NullPtr or a Null string, then the complete solution is:

```
int compareStore (const void*a, const void *b)
{
    const store *aa = a;
    const store *bb = b;

    // This MACRO retrieve ptr to last_name or company_name based
    // on whether last_name is a NULL ptr or a null "" string.
    // If last_name is either, use company_name insteadof last_name
    #define getKey(x) ((((x)->last_name==NULL)||((x)->last_name[0]==0)) ? (x)->company_name : (x)->last_name)

    // Use the Macro getKey to point to appropriate sort key for each record
    const char* keyA = getKey(aa);  
    const char* keyB = getKey(bb);

    return (strcmp(keyA, keyB));
}
```

Another bug is found in your call to `qsort` itself, where you pass the size of your list, but you should be passing the size of each record within the list to be sorted:

```
qsort (list, count, sizeof(store), compareStore);
```

Comment: I changed my function to the way you described and changed the qsort but it is arranging them by descending and it is also giving me warnings warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
   store *aa = a;
               ^
warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
   store *bb = b;

Comment: The double `*` notation would be correct if the array was an array of pointers.  It isn't, as you say, and the extra `*` is erroneous.

Comment: @AndreD'Souza: Add "const" in front of the definitions for aa and bb to get rid of the warnings. See edited answer.

Comment: Your updated program should sort in ascending order as I now understand it. Please update your question with the lastest version of your code. If you find it that the sorted order is descending, then try mulitplying the value returned by strcmp by -1 before returning it to qsort. This will reverse the sort.

Comment: I updated the question, I'm still stuck on ordering the Last name and Company name as one parameter. By the way Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Thanks @AndreD'Souza for updating your question. The reason your sort is descending rather than ascending is because you strcmp call has reversed the aa and bb parameters.

Comment: @AndreD'Souza: Given that your records will have EITHER a last name or a company name, the easiest solution would be to store company name in the last name field, and then the sort will cover both cases. If you want to keep them separate, then you must change your compare function to compare with last_name or company_name based on which one is present. How can yourcode tell which is name is present?

Comment: if i understanding this correctly if I store the last name and company name together just to sort them it will mix up the other struct parameters (eg. phonenumber, email) and when i print out the final output it will order the names but the other parameters will be out of sync

Comment: @AndreD'Souza: No, that is not what I am saying. But ignore combining them for now. How do you tell which is present in the record? Is one of last_name and company_name a nullptr or a null "" string?  Your code is hard to read, but if you tell me how you know which is being used, I can show you how to update your compare function to work.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, a reason segfaults can be so tricky to debug is that nothing *certainly* causes them. I’ve used compilers that allow `*NULL` (and heard of a programmer who tested for `NULL` by doing `strcmp(p, NULL)` and complained it was a bug if that didn’t evaluate to the string he expected). A program with undefined behavior might segfault on one run, work perfectly the next, segfault the third time in a different place, and on the fourth try give the wrong output. Making an end run around type safety into undefined behavior is a really bad idea in general.

Comment: @Davislor: We found the reasons for the segfaults: bad pointer math and invalid element size passed to qsort. He is no longer getting segfaults.

Comment: @ScottK Right. I’m just making two points here. One was that you don’t even have the assurance that, if the code seems to work, it doesn't have a hidden bug like this. It’s not predictable or portable. It doesn't even *certainly* segfault, but uncertsinly.

Comment: @ScottK Looking at the code again, my second point was correct, but unfair to the OP. Leaving on type checking in the function prototype would have caught this bug at compile time. However, he wrote it that way for a reason: the function is an input to a higher-order function.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because this looks like homework, but: if your `compareStore()` needs to compare *either* the last name *or* the company name, whichever is set, then it should contain a conditional.

In your case, you need a way to tell whether `last_name` or `company_name` is set.  You can set the unused pointer to `NULL` and test `if (a->last_name)`.  You could also add an `enum` field.

If you can change the definition of your `struct`, you don’t really need two `char *` fields that will be used the same way, only one at a time.  You can have one field, interpreted differently.

Finally, (Sorry for the unwarranted criticism.) you normally shouldn’t suppress static type checking like you did with the `void*` parameters.  It’s there to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.  In this case, though, the function is an input to `qsort()` and therefore one of the rare unavoidable exceptions.